# hide last column of datagrid doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I read some data from data**base** to data**table** and then shows the content of the datatable to data**grid**, the last column of the datatable us my primary key and I am trying to hide this column from the user, I have tried like:

In my XAML I have datagrid:

```
<DataGrid  Name="myDG" />
```

In code behind:

```
 public MyPage()
 {
   InitializeComponent();
   myDG.ItemsSource= this.myDataTable.DefaultView;//<-- dataTable with some data
   myDG.Columns[myDG.Columns.Count - 1].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;//<--- this line gives exeption
  }
```

I get the exeption:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

but if I add the line in some other place all works fine, I mean like:

```
void Some_Btn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   myDG.Columns[myDG.Columns.Count - 1].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
 // now it works fine and hides the last column
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because, by default the `DataGrid` makes the `AutoGenerateColumns = true` and your datagrid's `itemsource` are assigned in constructor, but the columns are not generated until they are displayed in window.

if you debug, and check the Columns in the DataGrid by below code in watch/Quick Watch.

```
 YourDataGridName.Columns.Count
```

This Count will be Zero.

Instead of handing visibility in Some_Btn or Button click event, do the same in Windows_Loaded event. 
your problem will be solved.

**Suggestion**:- If you have minimum number of columns instead of AutoGenerateColumns, create columns in DataGrid via Xaml.

Comment: Based on your answer, I added [OnLoad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-handle-a-loaded-event) event and it worked

Comment: @BugsFixer Gald was able to help you !